# How to re-write dataframe with new rows per column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame that looks like the following

| Name | Col 1 | Col 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 |
| B | 3 | 4 |

I'd like to change the dataset so that it has 2 columns, name and value. But I'd like to create a new row for each existing row combined with each column.

Like this:

| Name | Val |
| --- | --- |
| A-Col1 | 1 |
| A-Col2 | 2 |
| B-Col1 | 3 |
| B-Col2 | 4 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is one way do it, using melt

```
df2=df.melt(id_vars='Name')
df2['Name'] = df2['Name'] + '-' + df2['variable']
df2=df2.drop(columns='variable')
df2
```

```
    Name    value
0   A-Col 1     1
1   B-Col 1     3
2   A-Col 2     2
3   B-Col 2     4
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
 def combine_columns(df):
     df['combined'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['name'] + ' ' + row['value'], axis=1)
     return df
```

Comment: This proposed solution doesn't work? My data frame doesn't have a column named value, and even if it did, I wanted to create a new row for each existing row + each existing column.

Answer (score 0):

You can get pretty close very quickly using unstack and setting the `index` to `Name`:

```
df.set_index("Name").unstack().swaplevel()
```

gives

```
    Name
A     Col 1    1
B     Col 1    3
A     Col 2    3
B     Col 2    4
```

Now you have the right structure you just need to sort and merge. Combining in the sort and merge steps you can use:

```
tmp = (
    df.set_index("Name")
    .unstack()
    .swaplevel()
    .sort_index()
    .reset_index()
    .rename({0: "val"}, axis=1)
)
tmp["Name"] = tmp["Name"] + "-" + tmp["level_1"]
df = tmp.drop("level_1", axis=1)
```

to get

```
      Name  val
0  A-Col 1    1
1  A-Col 2    3
2  B-Col 1    3
3  B-Col 2    4
```

From your expected output you could use:

```
tmp["Name"] = tmp["Name"] + "-" + tmp["level_1"].str.replace(" ", "")
```

for the `Name` line as this will remove the space to give

```
     Name  val
0  A-Col1    1
1  A-Col2    3
2  B-Col1    3
3  B-Col2    4
```